# MikTeX: How to install language using miktex-console?

Tags: miktex

I'm running MiKTeX 2.9.6650 on an Ubuntu 16.04 machine. After successfully setting it up, I wanted to install additional languages.
That option used to be in the Settings, so I assumed to find it in the new `miktex-console`. As far as I can see, though, there is no such option: »Settings« has two tabs, »General« and »Directories«, but nothing relating to languages at all.

Am I missing something very obvious or has it just not been implemented yet? If the latter, how can I install additional languages without the console?

---

One year later: It seems, there still is no option to enable a language in my setup (I just tried with a fresh installation); a workaround that had been posted on github (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex/issues/136) does not work anymore, either. It seems, MikTeX is not an option under Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The tabs are already there in a current miktex (I checked both in miktex next and a standard miktex)

[image]

But there is no "add language button" (at least not in my single user installation, perhaps it is different for a multiuser installation). One only can enable and disable existing languages. So ff you want to add really new languages you will have to change the languages.ini manually.

Comment: Thank you for that info. Can you point me towards how do to switch my installation over to *MiKTeX Next*? Checking 'Retrieve pre-release packages' in the `Package Source` settings does not seem to change anything, at least no upadates are reported as being available.

Comment: Changing to "retrieve pre-release" worked for me. If you have a multiuser installation you problem need to do in admin mode as it mostly affects binaries.

Comment: The 'Language' tab is available on my non-next system as well (2.9.6677). So maybe a normal update suffices.

Comment: @moewe could be, I didn't check there yet.

Comment: Well, I did a fresh install immediately before asking so I thought I should have the newest version available. That, however, does not seem to be so – MiKTeX reports version 2.9.6650. I have a single user installation so that should not be the issue. – Well, it seems I'll just have to wait, probably the mirror accessed by the updater is not synced yet.

Comment: @dariok Even if you just performed a fresh installation it is possible that there are updates available. That's why https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex recommends to run the Console to update things after the installation process.

Comment: @moewe Indeed it does, and so I did update. As said, checking for updates, even after checking »retrieve pre-release packages«, returns »There are currently no updates available.«

Comment: @dariok Mhhh, weird. I think MikTeX automatically ignores mirrors that are out of date. I'm not on MikTeX next (»retrieve pre-release packages«), so I can't say anything about that. But even if you manage to get a version with 'language' tab that might not be enough, because my version (as Ulrike confirms in the answer for her version as well) does not actually have a function to add a language to the list.

Comment: @moewe I checked and I have the tabs too. I edited the answer.

Comment: The mirrors are reported to be up-to-date (3rd May, that is). So I'm really puzzled by now.
And yes, I understand that I cannot add a completely new language to the list; I was looking to „enable“ additional languages (which involves installing additional data, if not yet present in the installation, hence my choice of words).

Comment: I used as last mirror fu-berlin and it worked fine. If you really don't get updates, ask on the github site of miktex.

Comment: By now, a new MiKTeX build has been made available for Linux. The problem, however, is not solved. Initially, all languages were checked (but none had an entry under "installed").

Comment: I have now completely uninstalled MiKTeX and reinstalled it. Again, all languages were checked but none said anything under "installed".
`gloss-*` files are present, but polyglossia claims "unknown language german"; unchecking all languages, building, rechecking and building did not help. Any ideas?

Comment: gloss-files are not hyphenation patterns. You need the hyph-utf8 package for most languages. Beside this: It is quite possible that something is wrong here, but then you should make a bug report to miktex.

Comment: hyph-utf8 is present, too. I'll open an issue on github.
Thanks for your help!