# LaTeX suddenly stopped working on 3 machines

Tags: pdftex, windows

LaTeX suddenly stopped working on several machines that I use. I'm using Texmaker 5.0.2 and MiKTeX 2.9.

I get this error:

```
Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

I get the same error for `latex` command when I try to build using dvi-ps-pdf. I tried running `pdflatex` and `latex` commands in `cmd` without any input arguments, and the system can find these programs. However, when I try to build a simple test file as:

```
pdflatex test.tex
```

I get the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6700 64-bit)
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

What's going on?

Comment: Try to recreate the formats (miktex console, settings, tab format. Select pdflatex and click on build, or change something in the language tabs. You probably should do this in the user version of the console.).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I don't have the "Format" tab under settings. I have only "General" and "Directories".

Comment: Then your system is not up-to-date, it should be there see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/430053/2388. If you don't want to update you can try to find and use the old miktex settings  (mo.exe).

Comment: On one of the machines that didn't have MiKTeX installed, I installed the last version this morning from https://miktex.org/download and it also does not have the "Formats" and "Languages" tabs.

Comment: As https://miktex.org/download says "When you have installed MiKTeX, it is recommended that you start MiKTeX Console in order to get the latest updates.". (If you have a multiuser installation you should check for updates with admin + user mode)

Comment: That was the first thing I did when it wasn't working :)

Comment: Try on a command line `initexmf --dump`  to create the formats.

Comment: Tried it with admin privileges, still does not work with the same message. Since it does not work on three machines, I'd say that the cause is some Windows update.

Comment: Try without admin privileges.

Comment: Still no luck..

Comment: What is the output of `initexmf --dump=pdflatex`?

Comment: Nothing, it just finishes the operation and prints a blank line.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich -engine=pdftex pdflatex.fmt` say? Is the date of the file it points to current?

Comment: The response is: C:/Users/user/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/data/le/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt